# Возможна ли точка после «?!»?

Tags: пунктуация, многоточие

Существует сочетание многоточия с вопросительным знаком или многоточия с возклицательным знаком, но возможно ли сочетание их всех сразу? Допустим: «Ты кто?!.»

Answer (score 5):

Вот как на подобный вопрос отвечала справочная служба русского языка Грамоты.ру:

> **Вопрос № 270133**
>
> Добрый день! Ни в одном справочнике нет правила сочетания трех знаков
> подряд: вопросительный, восклицательный и многоточие. Надеюсь на вашу
> помощь. Поглощают ли "?" и "!" по одной точке из "...", или только "!"
> поглощает первую точку из "..."?  Как правильно: ?!. или ?!..
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Интересный вопрос. В справочниках такого, действительно, нет. Или
> почти нет. Давайте рассуждать. Есть правило: после вопросительного или
> восклицательного знака ставятся не три точки (обычный вид многоточия),
> а две. Правило основано на том, что первая точка стоит под одним из
> названных знаков. Значит, при сочетании трех знаков надо оставить
> только одну точку: ?!. Первая и вторая точки стоят под вопросительным
> и восклицательным знаками. И еще один аргумент в пользу такого
> сочетания: в «Полном академическом справочнике» под ред. В. В.
> Лопатина (М., 2006), в предметном указателе к разделу «Пунктуация»,
> сочетание знаков ?!. указано в ряду с ?.. и !.., хотя в самом правиле
> и в примерах к нему оно не приводится.

[http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=№%20270133](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=%E2%84%96%20270133)

Answer (score 3):

*Возможна ли точка после **«?!»**?*
Да, возможна.
Максимальное число ***нижних*** точек — три (многоточие и есть по факту ***трое**точие*).
Если вместо какой-либо из точек имеется вопросительный или восклицательный знак (а каждый их них имеет **внизу** считаемую по правилам точку), то максимальное их [точек] количество не может превышать указанное — три. Остальное — авторский выбор.

М. А. Булгаков ("Собачье сердце"): *Но я не Айседора **Дункан!!***

М. А. Булгаков ("Мастер и Маргарита"):

> И вдруг за столиком вспорхнуло слово: **«Берлиоз!!»** Вдруг джаз развалился и затих, как будто кто-то хлопнул по нему кулаком. **«Что, что, что, что?!!» — «Берлиоз!!!»** И пошли вскакивать, пошли вскакивать...

А. П. Чехов ("Маска"): *Все расписавшись? **Ну, теперь глядите!.. Раз... два... три!!.***

Comment: На тему поглощения точек есть весьма интересное мнение: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=298906

Comment: Спасибо, это мнение я уже видела (оно представлено в ответе Славы). *Я предлагаю считать грамотным такое сочетание знаков: «?!..». Ответ справочной службы русского языка: Мы передадим Ваше предложение в Орфографическую комиссию РАН. Спасибо!* Видать, еще не порешили.