# Два восклицательных знака и многоточие

Tags: пунктуация, переводы

В японской манге некоторые предложения оканчиваются "*слово*...!", "*слово*...?", "*слово*...!?" и т.д. При переводе на русский, понятно, это становится "*слово*!..", "*слово*?..", "*слово*?!." Но что если в оригинале идёт два восклицательных знака? "*слово*...!!" Должны ли эти два восклицательных знака заменять точки? "*слово*!!." Или же стоит убрать один из восклицательных знаков? "*слово*!.."

Comment: Вот здесь (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/468199/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5/468203#468203) есть полезные разъяснения, ссылка и другие примеры предложений (кроме уже использованных в ответе).

Answer (score 0):

Среди современных составных знаков знака с двумя вопросами или двумя восклицательными не существует.

Однако есть примеры из классики, где подобная пунктуация встречается:

- > Ну, теперь глядите!.. Раз... два... три!!. (Чехов)
- > И вдруг за столиком вспорхнуло слово: «Берлиоз!!» (Булгаков)

Трактовать можно двояко: и как "разрешение" на такие знаки, и как то, что на момент создания цитируемых текстов просто не было ещё современных правил.

Более того, в действующих правилах пунктуации вообще нет разрешения использовать подряд два и больше вопросительных или восклицательных знаков (то есть даже распространённые конструкции наподобие *"?!!"* или *"!!!"* — это авторская пунктуация, тем не менее часто встречающаяся).

Лично я использую двойной знак только в случае "нарастания", парцелляционного эмоционального "накидывания": *Он увидел её!.. Одну!!. С тремя пакетами!!! Это был шанс показать себя мужиком.*

Вот на основании вышесказанного вам придётся решать, как поступить. Лично я в манге встречал неоднократно сочетание *"!!."* и подобные, и вроде никто из русскоязычных мангак и сканлейтеров не парится.